# Django Web Application with beautiful soup , request

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, request

I would like to have a website when a user enters something then they get all scrape data views on the website..

For now with this python3 code working fine via jupyter notebook.
you guys can test it in jupyter notebook. But I want in proper ways which are for the user interface. I know Django can integrate with python code but where should i put this code. is it models.py?

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen as uReq 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def make_soup(website) :

    req =  Request(website,headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    uClient = uReq(req)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
    return page_soup

google_news_url = 'https://www.google.com.my/search?q={}&source=Int&tbm=nws'

def forge_url (q):
    return google_news_url.format(q.replace(' ','+'))

news_url = forge_url (input('Enter Search'))
website = make_soup(news_url)
headlines = website.findAll('h3')
n = 0
for item in headlines :
    top = item.a
    #print(top)
    #print()
    text_headlines = top.text
    print(text_headlines)
    print()
    n +=1
```

Btw what should I put at views.py and templates also. Thanks ;)

Comment: You put it in views.py.

Answer (score 0):

Scraping is a pretty time consuming task,

It takes a lot of time to get the data, and even more to process the data.

So in order to make a good website doing scraping is that you have to define some background tasks doing the job while users can do something else or see a process bar.

Also not all websites are server-side rendered so you can't get the page data with requests or other libraries like it. You can use selenium to open the page with a browser (Firefox and Chrome), render the full page and then pass the source to libraries like BS in order to extract the desired content.

So my recommendation is:

- to build a view to ask for page url,
- Create one or more background tasks to do the heavy work (With celery for example)
- and then pass the result to user when the process is finished.

You can find named libraries here:

[Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)